# Nav & Cart Menu Issue not expanding not collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, debugging

The website I am customizing is http://flamelogs.com. When I resize my window for mobile view the cart menu expands and cannot collapse and the nav menu does not expand. Everything is fine when the window is at normal view. I really don't have great experience with Javascript/Jquery so I don't know how to troubleshoot this. If someone could please inspect the element and give me some help I would greatly appreciate it. I received the error about where Jquery targets the `ul.accordion` `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

jQuery("ul.accordion li.parent").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).append('<em class="open-close">&nbsp;</em>');
  });

jQuery('ul.accordion').accordionNew();

jQuery("ul.accordion li.active").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).children().next("ul").css('display', 'block');
});
```

});

Comment: Your first issue to resolve is that the console shows you a javascript error.  The second issue is that using jQuery in Magento, you must be careful - Magento already comes fully loaded with Scriptaculous, and you may have colissions.  Finally, without knowing where in the world you want us to look for your menu javascript, we cannot help.  Magento comes with thousands and thousands of lines of javascript. You *must* copy / paste the relevant bits of code to your question.

Comment: Thanks for that, I assumed one could pull that info from the developer tools. I guess I am showing off how novice I am to debugging. Hope my re-edit clears some things up.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has predefined library of function. You are used following code in script. Where accordionNew() is not predefined function of Jquery Library so this issues shows in console of your browser. Please use predefine function. 

TypeError: jQuery(...).accordionNew is not a function

jQuery('ul.accordion').accordionNew();
 
Please remove this code.